# Animating height & width changes to masonry grid layout. CSS grid alternatives?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I am building a "masonry"-style layout where all boxes are primarily the same height and width, but I want to *highlight* a few boxes by increasing their width and height.

[image: (like this!)]

I want periodically change which of the boxes are highlighted (some may shrink back to the original size and others may grow).

I have built the layout above using CSS grid and by toggling the `top` and `highlighted` classes with JavaScript I can achieve what I want:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 5.5%);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.container .box {
  border: 1px solid black;

  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: 1;
}

.container .box.top {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.container .box.highlighted {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box top"></div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box top"></div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box top"></div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box highlighted"></div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box top"></div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
    <div class="box">-</div>
</div>
```

I would like to animate the transition when toggling the `top` or `highlighted` classes, but I don't know how to do this?

Is this possible with CSS grid (from what I can find online I don't think so)?

If not, can I achieve this layout/effect with other techniques?

**NOTE: This doesn't need to be cross-browser (just Google Chrome) and I can use JavaScript to help - it doesn't need to be pure CSS**

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use javascript to change the element class -- elm.className="...", or maybe elm.className+=(space) and new class.

Comment: @TonyDuffill I am comfortable with the JavaScript to change the classes.  It's animating the change in state for the boxes that I am looking to achieve.

Comment: Ok, so I haven't understood - what do you mean by 'animating the change'? - I assumed you just wanted to turn the classes on or off programmatically ...

Comment: @TonyDuffill ideally I would just add `transition: all 0.5s;` to the *box* class and when I changed the `grid-row` or `grid-column` value for that box the change in size would animate automatically. I want to know if this is possible when using CSS Grid for this layout, or if I have to use a different technique (e.g. Flexbox, JavaScript plugin, etc).

Comment: Well now... transition applied to classes is not my speciality subject. From what you say I suspect that you want to detect changes in the value (or innerHTML) of your boxes and react accordingly. I have never dealt with this without using javascript. I don't think it matters whether you use Grid or Flex layout -- but someone may know better than me...

Comment: As far as I can understand from [w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) - only 5 grid properties are _Animatable_: `grid-gap`, `grid-row-gap`, `grid-column-gap`, `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows`. That means you cannot animate `grid-row` or `grid-column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I managed to animate my current layout using [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/animate-css-grid).